# How to move subscription logic from ngOnInit to ngOnChange

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

This is a more generell question regarding Angular - which I am pretty new to - being a React-nerd all-through.

I have a task to move logic to ngOnChanges covering each cases when we should subscribe, keep the existing subsciption or unsubscribe. How do I do that?

This is some example code:

```
ngOnInit() {

    const obsValue$ = combineLatest([
        this.store.pipe(select(this.example1Selector.getData())),
        this.store.pipe(select(this.example2Selector.getData()))
    ]).pipe(
        tap(([important1, important2]) => {
            this.important1 = important1;
            this.important2 = important2;
        })
    );
}
```

I want to move this code to the ngOnChange and subscribe to in only when needed and keep it when necessary and unsubscribe when necessary. How do I do that?

Comment: Question one - why do you think you can't? Question two - why would you? It's a very broad question and you give no details

Comment: Your quesion needs some more detail, whats the goal? Please provide some more information and show some code if you can. How to handle subscription depends on the case. If your component is a child i wouldnt subscripe "by hand" at all and use the async pipe instead. In principle just moving subscriptions from ngOninit to ngOnchanges should't be a poblem, but it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: I updated with a little more info so it is clearer what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unsubscribe subscriptions you don't longer need either by calling `Subscription#unsubscribe` (requires you to save `Subscriptions`) or by ending event stream with `Subject#complete` which finalizes all subscriptions - but that is not always applicable.

Failing to do so can lead to resource leaks. (that depends on actual observable and if it is closed as some point or not)

Also I usually unsubscribe/complete in ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook as well.